# Spring error handling does not work

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

There are many topics, but... I have proper return parameters and arguments, I read, that this is necessary. What is wrong?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vse.uslugi.utilities.web.BaseDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class BaseDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleThrowable() {
    return ErrorService.html("Internal server error");
}

@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
    return ErrorService.html("Page not found");
}
}
//--------------------
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher servlet is being instantiated by your application server so it's probably not spring managed.

Some options you have:

1. Add the `@ExceptionHandler` method to the controller.
2. Add a bean to your spring context that has the `@ExceptionHandler` methods on it and annotate the class with `@ControllerAdvice`, this will apply it to all controllers by default.